# Why does Safari/WebKit appends .html to downloaded files?

Tags: php, http, safari, download, mime

I'm having lot of issues with Safari. When I provide a download from a PHP script the downloaded file has ".html" extension appended. Despite the HTTP headers I send to the client, I found them changed in inspector; in particular the mime-type is always set to `text/html`.

Here what I'm sending to the browser:

```
<?php 

....

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$file['name']}\"");
header("Content-Type: ".$file['type']?$file['type']:'application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file['file']));

ob_end_flush();
@readfile($file['file']);
```

Where $file contains:

```
$file = array(
  'name'=>'myfile.zip',
  'file'=>'/tmp/myfile.zip',
  'type'=>'application/zip'
);
```

What can I do?

Comment: Don't you have any `Headers already sent` errors? Are all headers you mentioned here present but changed or there are some missing?

Comment: use `header("Content-Type: $file['type']");`

Comment: You don't by any chance have a .htaccess file or apache directive rewriting URLs with .html on the end do you?  Failing that - just for the hell of it what happens if you just serve it as `application/octet-stream` regardless?

Comment: Unerelated, but anyway: remove all invalid/undefined header fields: Content-Description, Content-Transfer-Encoding, most options on Cache-Control.

Comment: Thank you all for comments, but only webkit browsers are having problems, Firefox and IE are performing ok, so: @dev-null-dweller : I don't have any header error, Amir  ..actually it's what happening in runtime. Emissary if i send application/octet-stream i have the same issue.. and there are no rules in .htaccess.  Julian Reschke : yes.. I just tried to fill most of data I could.